# Ada why check if an objects length is not equal to itself. Ex if(variable'Length /= variable'length)

Tags: ada, codepeer

I am reviewing some ada code and I keep seeing the following code throughout the project.

```
if(variable'Length /= variable'length)
   return;
end if
```

Codepeer flags this as always false which makes perfect sense to me, but I have very little ada experience. Is this valid, and if so under what circumstance would it be true?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks to me like crazy code, written by someone who needs a good thump with the cluebat. I’d reject it immediately (especially if it’s in a project serious enough to warrant paying for Codepeer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never.  You can only ask for the length of an array object, and once that object has been declared, it can't change.

Comment: Thanks, I know this sounds like a stupid question but ada is completely outside my comfort zone.

Comment: Don't worry about that.  If the value of the variable had been involved, another task could - theoretically - change the two sides of the comparison between their evaluation.

Comment: For values it could make sense, but then it would indicate that you have race conditions and any such checks are only bandaid.

Comment: I just tried a simple version and the compiler completely eliminates the test and the `return` - even with no optimisation (`-O0`).